# Custom authorization check before executing controller

Tags: symfony, authorization, symfony-routing

I've added a new option `roles` in  routing settings for checking permissions for menu items during a menu rendering.
It would be great if I could use the option for authorization check before executing corresponding controllers.

**Example:**

```
some_route:
    path: /path/
    defaults:   { _controller: MyBundle:Controller:action }
    option:
        roles: [ROLE_MANAGER, ROLE_ADMIN]
```

I need check if user has access to the controller based on his roles before executing controller itself.
How does it possible? Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
Why I need the `roles` option?
There are 4 different roles and many routes in the project. Some of routes are protected and visible only for users with specific roles.
For now all authorization checks are performed inside controllers by `denyAccessUnlessGranted()` method.
I also use [KnpMenuBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle) for building menu. And during the menu rendering I need check accessibility of each item for a current logged-in user. If the user has no access to an item it is excluded and the user doesn't see it.
In order to check if user has access to an item or not I added the option I've mentioned, where I define roles which have access to a route. And this `roles` options defines absolutely the same roles as in checks in `denyAccessUnlessGranted()`. And I think as I already have these role settings why don't use it for controller authorization checks and remove redundant code from them.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: @Frankbeen, I've added some explanations in the Update section. Hope you understand me, if don't then please feel free for asking details =)

Comment: Add a kernel.controller listener and check the permissions there: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-controller

Comment: @Cerad thank you, that's what I was looking for! Can you please add a new answer and copy your comment in order I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is not much of an answer but you asked for it.

Add a [kernel.controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-controller) listener and check the permissions there.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, two ways

1. **Security.yml**

   ```
   - { path: ^/path/$, roles: [ROLE_MANAGER, ROLE_ADMIN] }
   ```
2. **Annotations directly into controller**

   ```
   /**
    * @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN') or has_role('ROLE_MANAGER')")
    */
   public function nameOfYourAction()
   ```

That way, the very first action done before controller's action execution is security check: if this fails, controller will not be executed.

Comment: Thanks, but I actually need this options for checking if a user has access to menu items or not during KnpMenu rendering. I've added some explanations of it to the question.
If I define roles that has access to a controller by `@Security` annotation then I won't be able to get these settings during menu rendering ... or I will?

Comment: @basil I'll take a look when I'll get some extra free time, hopefully today ;)